# Should I get rid of a cursor object after using it?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am creating a cursor object to opearate in an sqlite3 database. Should I not only close the connection, but also delete the object after using it? Is this needed? Is it memory-efficient?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("xyz.db")


class Cursor2():

    def __enter__(self):
        global conn
        self.cur = conn.cursor()
        return self.cur

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.cur.close()
        del self.cur
```

Comment: By memory-effective, do you actually mean memory-efficient?

Comment: Yes, english is not my first language. Already edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not needed. Python does automatic [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))  so, in general, you would not need to worry about deleting your objects, especially for smaller applications. Closing the connection is sufficient.